# Retirar grifado no editor do Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Como tirar esse grifado automatico do Android Studio?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Ele provavelmente está recomendando utilizar [string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource) com formatação.

Comment: Nesse caso sim, mas esse grifado aparece aleatoriamente e geralmente em arquivos xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O amarelo em questão é, na verdade, um grifado do lint indicando um possível problema ou melhoria que pode ser aplicada no seu código. Você pode ler mais sobre o funcionamento do lint na [documentação](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint), assim como formas de configurá-lo.

Normalmente os avisos podem ser ignorados, mas o ideal é lê-los, entender as possíveis implicações do problema indicado e aplicar as correções necessárias. Inclusive, algumas correções podem ser aplicadas automaticamente ao pressionar `alt+enter`.

Nesse caso em específico, o lint provavelmente está indicando para usar [string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource), que, entre outras vantagens, facilita a tradução do seu aplicativo para outros idiomas.